# SQL Server - fastest way to select max / min item from the joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Hypothetical situation.

As requested by a comment adding more details regarding the dataset:

1. Table Orders: < 10 mln of rows.
2. Table Orders_Log < 200 mln (v. rough approximation).
3. Most of the applications will limit order rows in `Orders` table to 50k - 1 mln, with 80% queries in < 100k. --> (`WHERE` clause on the `FROM` table will limit the number of rows to 100k based on the `Category` of the order of type `VARCHAR`).
4. Indexes for the given scenario: on `Category` and `OrderId` .
5. `OderId` is of type `VARCHAR`

Table "Orders" contains completed orders history.

```
| OrderID | Customer | NoOfItems | Category
```

Table "Orders_log" is a log table, which stores actions related to the order and time when the action ocurred. It is joined by Order ID. It's 1..* relationship.

```
| RowId | OrderId | Action | DateTime
```

I am looking for a fastest way join first entry (chronologically) that matches specific action, say: 'Item added to a cart'

My proposal:

```
SELECT
    [OrderId]
,   [Action]
,   [NumberOfitems]
FROM
    Orders o
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
                [OrderId]
            ,   [Action]
            ,   MIN(ActionTime)
        FROM
                Orders_Log
        WHERE   
                [Action] = 'XYZ'
        GROUP BY
                [OrderId]
            ,   [Action]

    ) ordersLog
    ON  o.[OrderId]
        =   
        ordersLog.[OrderID]
```

Can we get something faster though? The number of entries in the Orders_Log table, matching specific action for a given OrderId will vary from 1-50 with 80% of values in 1-8.

Comment: There just aren't enough details here to provide an accurate answer. Table definitions (including indexes), approximate row counts etc at the very least.

Comment: row_number() is usually faster than aggregate--but these are going to be your two main options

Comment: For the given scenario. Table Orders: < 10 mln of rows. Table Orders_Log < 200 mln. Most of the applications will limit order rows to 50k - 1 mln with 80% queries in < 100k. (WHERE clause on the `FROM` table will limit the number of  rows to 100k based on the `Category` of the order, which is VARCHAR). Indexes for the given scenario: on 'Category' and 'OrderId' . I hope this makes sense - I am not a DBA.

Comment: is there an action that would be queried more often than the other actions?

Comment: side note, i'd close this and post on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the following produces the desired results...

```
SELECT 
    o.OrderId,
    o.[Action],
    o.NumberOfItems,
    xol.FirstAction,
    xol.LastAction
FROM
    dbo.Orders o
    CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT 
                    FirstAction = MIN(ol.ActionTime),
                    LastAction = MAX(ol.ActionTime)
                FROM
                    dbo.Orders_Log ol
                WHERE 
                    o.OrderId = ol.Order_Id
                    AND ol.[Action] = 'XYZ'
                ) xol;
```

As far as squeezing the maximum performance out of it... You could try adding the following indexed view...

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.iv_OrdersLog_FirstLastXYZAction 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
    SELECT 
        ol.Orders_Id,
        FirstAction = MIN(ol.ActionTime),
        LastAction = MAX(ol.ActionTime),
        cb = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM
        dbo.Orders_Log ol
    WHERE 
        ol.[Action] = 'XYZ'
    GROUP BY 
        ol.Order_Id;
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX cix_ivOrdersLogFirstLastXYZAction ON dbo.iv_OrdersLog_FirstLastXYZAction (Orders_Id);
```

In which case, the query would look like the following...

```
SELECT 
    o.OrderId,
    o.[Action],
    o.NumberOfItems,
    vol.FirstAction,
    vol.LastAction
FROM
    dbo.Orders o
    JOIN dbo.iv_OrdersLog_FirstLastXYZAction vol  WITH (NOEXPAND)
        ON o.OrderId = vol.Order_Id
WHERE 
    o.[Action] = 'XYZ';
```

HTH,
Jason